# RxJS - Using zip to parallelize deferred Observables that make HTTP requests not working - You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected

Tags: node.js, rxjs

I am running a Node.js API endpoint that has to paralellize several HTTP calls in one of its endpoints.

Using the Star Wars API as an example. I get a user info by id. It contains an array of films and I want to parallelize the retrieval of all those films information.

After getting the person info I create an array of observables, each of them getting one of the films. The I set up a zip operator to compose the results of all the gotten films.

The point is, after subscribing I see n times, one per film, the `console.log(filmData)` information, which is correct. But it seems as if the zip callback with the `console.log("*********************************************************************");` is not called. Neither are the next, error, complete callbacks.

Why could this be?

```
client.get("https://swapi.co/api/people/"+uid, args, (data, response) => {
    var filmsIt = data.films;
    for(var i in filmsIt){
        var observable = Rx.Observable.defer(function () {
            client.get(filmsIt[i], args, (filmData, filmResponse) => {
                console.log(filmData);
                return filmData;
            });
        });
        observables.push(observable);
    }
    var observableFinal = Rx.Observable.zip(...observables, function() {
        console.log("*********************************************************************");
    }).subscribe(
        function (x) {
            console.log('Next: ' + x);
        },
        function (err) {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
        },
        function () {
            console.log('Completed');
        });
});
```

**UPDATE:** following martin's answer, the callbacks are invoked. However, I get this error now:

```
Error: TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

I have changed the deferred function to return an Observable like this:

```
var observable = Rx.Observable.defer(function () {
            return Rx.Observable.of(client.get(filmsIt[i], args, (filmData, filmResponse) => {
                console.log(filmData);
                return filmData;
            });
        }));
```

The problem is that, now the zip function isn't getting the actual values of the HTTP calls, but a bunch of ClientRequest objects:

```
  { '0': 
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        href: 'https://swapi.co/api/films/7/',
        options: [Object],
        _httpRequest: [Object] },
     '1': 
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        href: 'https://swapi.co/api/films/7/',
        options: [Object],
        _httpRequest: [Object] },
      ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `Observable.defer` you need to return an Observable from the callback function (or Promise or whatever, see http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObservableInputDoc.html).

I guess you wanted to do something like this:

```
var observable = Rx.Observable.defer(function () {
    return client.get(filmsIt[i], args, (filmData, filmResponse) => {
        console.log(filmData);
        return filmData;
    });
});
```

Comment: Ups I was missing that. However, although the callbacks are now invoked it still doesn't work as expected. Could you please have a look at the updated question?

Comment: I guess the `client.get` method doesn't return any of the supported objects listed in http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObservableInputDoc.html). Or try not using `Rx.Observable.of`

Answer (score 0):

martin was right in his answer about the need to return a valid type from the deferred function.

Just to make it clear, I solved it using Q to wrap the http client library and returning a promise this way:

```
function httpGet(url, args){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    client.get(url, args, (data, response) => {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

exports.getFilms = (uid) => { 

    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var observables = [];
    var toReturn;

    httpGet("https://swapi.co/api/people/"+uid, args)
    .then( (data) => {
        toReturn = data;
        data.films.forEach(function (filmsIt){
            var observable = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(httpGet(filmsIt, args));     
            observables.push(observable);
        });
        var observableFinal = Rx.Observable.zip(...observables, function() {
            toReturn.films = arguments;
            return arguments;
        }).subscribe(
            (x) => {},
            (err) => {console.log('Error: ' + err);},
            () => {
                deferred.resolve(toReturn);
            });
    });     
    return deferred.promise;
}
```